# Selection options for Page Range inadequate?

Tags: feature-request, search, usability, navigation

I find the range of options quite limiting, in terms of the Page Range.  For example, at the bottom of a typical search or list, I encounter this:

[image: SE typical page advancer thingy]

Oftentimes, I would like to jump somewhere in the middle of the list, or towards the back, or just not in the first 5 pages! Needless to say, Google has found success with their somewhat funky solution to this problem:

[image: Google gets the middle of the search right]

It's small, you may call it stupid...  but I breathe, sleep and, ahem, do other things just like everyone else... And I sorta can't deal with how it is now...  Any plans for a rethink in this department?  How about an infinite scroll?  That'd kill this bird, and make interaction waaay sexier.  I'd guess infinite scroll might have page view implications, in terms of advertiser metrics, etc... but surely this bright group could figure out a way around that, no?

For clarity, I have attached a representation of what I'm talking about (in the style of a cracked-out 8-year-old, with only Preview.app installed on his computer), below.

[image: low budget copy and paste infographic]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh C'mon, we're all programmers ;P Why don't you just change the url from `...search?page=1..` to `...search?page=30000..` (or `...questions?page=30000...` depending if you're searching or not) You tagged it search so I assumed you were, but then 37000 pages is a lot)

Comment: ugh, so practical and resilient to my whimseys...  such is life, ech..